# How to add a string into a vector in a switch case menu in C++

Tags: c++, vector, switch-statement, game-development

The task I have is to make a vector of strings, append strings to it, and delete strings from it. I am having trouble with append strings.I  also have it set up so that the switch case gives the option to append the queue in case 1.

```
//gaming Queue

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int choice;
   string input;
   bool menu = true;  
   vector<string> favGames;
   while (menu){
       cout <<"Welcome to the favorite game queue please add your favorite games:\n";
       cout <<"1-Add a favorite game.\n";
       cout <<"2-List of your favorite games.\n";
       cout <<"3-Remove a game.\n";
       cin  >> choice;  
       switch (choice)
          {
             case 1:    
                cout << "Please add a favorite game to the queue: \n";
                string input;
                cin >> input;
                favGames.push_back(input);// Here is my problem it just jumps to case 2 and shows an error 
                break;
            case 2: 
                cout << "Here is a list of your favorite games.\n";
                break;

            default:
                cout << "You made an illegal choice.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you declare `string input` a second time.

Comment: The only way this code can jump to case 2 is if the user actually enters 2 as input. And you say there is an error, but you don't say what the error actually is.

Comment: @Seltymar if its needed only once Should I declare it in the case or outside?

Comment: @RemyLebeau the problem i am having is that i cant add to my vector with the push_back(input)

Comment: @RemyLebeau You have to declare it outside the switch.

Comment: @Seltymar okay so now it runs the program but doesn't allow the user to input in anything

Comment: @Migdotcom I don't see where is the problem, I can enter anything and print it also.

Comment: @Seltymar So new error i get is that it after putting in the sentence i want i get a infinite loop disobeying the break after case one

Comment: @Migdotcom I have updated my answer with the full code, let me know if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling your code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler, it shows me those error:

```
main.cpp:34:18: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
         case 2: 
              ^
main.cpp:30:24: note:   crosses initialization of 'std::string input'
             string input;
```

as you can see the compiler tells you that you're skipping the initialization of  `string input`. At the same time you are declaring `input` a second time.
By removing `input` inside the switch case, the program compiles and works as intended.

**EDIT:**

You can't enter more than one word using cin because `cin` extraction always considers spaces (whitespaces, tabs, new-line...) as terminating the value being extracted.

So you have to use `getline`. Same for when getting `choice`.

here is the full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    string input;
    bool menu = true;
    vector<string> favGames;
    while (menu) {
        cout << "Welcome to the favorite game queue please add your favorite games:\n";
        cout << "1-Add a favorite game.\n";
        cout << "2-List of your favorite games.\n";
        cout << "3-Remove a game.\n";

        string choiceStr;
        getline(cin, choiceStr);
        stringstream(choiceStr) >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Please add a favorite game to the queue: \n";
            getline(cin, input);
            favGames.push_back(input);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Here is a list of your favorite games.\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "No longer like a game which game should we remove?\n";
            break;

        default:
            cout << "You made an illegal choice.\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why it enters infinite loop:

The `cin >> input` can only work when you enter only one word. If you enter several words, the `cin >> input` will catch the first one then the `cin >> choice` will catch the next one. If the input catch by `cin >> choice` is not an int, the `cin` will fail which makes you an infinite loop in this case. 
It is explained here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/.

Comment: Thank you that did! Could please explain what the problem was it seems that get line was the trick but still confused on why i didn't work the first time

Answer (score 2):

`switch` statements are a bit weird because you can't declare variables inside the `case` clauses unless you create a scope for them using a `{}` block.

```
   switch (choice)
   {
         case 1:    
         { // start a scope  
            cout << "Please add a favorite game to the queue: \n";
            string input;
            cin >> input;
            favGames.push_back(input);// Here is my problem it just jumps to case 2 and shows an error 
            break;
         } // end the scope
```

However in your case you already defined a `std::string` outside the `switch`, did you intend to use that? Then you can just remove the one inside the `case` clause.